# Locking indexer programmatically

Tags: magento-1, indexing

I tried locking my indexer programmatically with this code as I used to do:

```
$indexer = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
            $indexer->lockIndexer();
```

I noticed that my indexer didn't get locked and when i went looking in the core files I saw it was deprecated. Is there any other way to lock the indexer? I looked into it and didn't exactly see one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just `touch` the lock file.

```
<?php touch('BP.DS.'var'.DS.'locks'.DS.'index_process_1.lock')
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /home/path/public_html/var/locks/index_process_1.lock
```

This is obviously a low quality solution - but if you wanted to perform this action peripherally to Magento (eg. from a `bash` script, it would be suitable).

---

Otherwise, the methods you need are in `Mage_Index_Model_Process`

Such as `isLocked()`, `lockAndBlock()`, and `unlock()`

Assuming your module extends said class, you need only declare

```
const PROCESS_ID = 'my_indexer'
```

And use the methods as appropriate

```
$this->lockAndBlock();
```

Comment: Don't really agree with creating them with touch as i rather go the Magento way but lockAndBlock did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

You can lock each index process individually:

```
Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(x)->lock();
```

Comment: Does it return true if lock succeeds and false if not?